# Are there infinitely many positive integer solutions to the equation $\overline{x^2y^2} = z^2\,$?

Tags: number-theory

> Do there exist infinitely many solutions to the equation $$\overline{x^2y^2} = z^2$$ where $x,y,z$ are positive integers? Note: the notation $\overline{xy}$ means a concatenation of the numbers $x$ and $y$ to form one number.

One solution to this equation is $(x,y,z) = (4,9,41)$. Then we have $\overline{4^29^2} = 1681 = 41^2$. If $y = \overline{a_1 \ldots a_n}$, then $\overline{x^2y^2} = 10^{2n} x^2+y^2 = z^2$, but I didn't see how to find infinitely many integer solutions to this.

Comment: It might be useful to explain that the notation (overline) $\overline{x^2y^2} = z^2$ indicates that you are asking whether there are infinitely many solutions to the concatenation of $x^2 $ with $y^2$, in that order, which is equal to square of some integer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I just went to Wikipedia and the Vinculum article doesn't even include concatenation as a possible use.

Comment: Also $\,(2,3,7)\,$.

Comment: If we take y=1,then we get 10x^2+1=z^2 which gives z^2-10x^2=1 .Since,this is  a positive pell 
equation and thus have infinitely many solutions.
Does this solution work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\overline{2^2(3\cdot10^k)^2}=(7\cdot10^k)^2$$
and in general, if $(a,b,c)$ is a solution, then so is $(a,b\cdot10^k,c\cdot10^k)$

Comment: @KitterCatter Yes; you end up being able to factor out the squared power of $10$

Answer (score 0):

A preliminary report on using an idea that should give us many solutions.

---

Possibly more interesting (=avoiding trailing zeros in $z$) examples can be found as follows.

Recall the parametrization of Pythagorean triples:
$$a=2mn,\quad b=m^2-n^2,\quad c=m^2+n^2.$$

Compare this with the equation

$$10^{2k}x^2+y^2=z^2$$
that the OP derived.

We want to set things up in such a way that $a=10^kx$, $b=y$ and $c=z$.
A way to use this is to select $m=m'\cdot 5^k$ and $n=n'\cdot 2^k$, and then arrange $y=m^2-n^2$, or actually $y^2$, to have the correct number of digits. This is not entirely trivial, but probably can be analyzed further without having to work too hard.

**Example.**
The choice $m=2\cdot 5^4, n=78\cdot 2^4$ gives the following
$$
\begin{aligned}
a&=3\,120\,000,\\
x&=312,\\
y&=4996,\\
z&=3\,120\,004,\\
x^2&=97\,344,\\
y^2&=24\,960\,016,\\
z^2&=9\,734\,424\,960\,016.
\end{aligned}
$$
Observe that taking out the common factor $2$ from these choices of $m$ and $n$, IOW $m=5^4$, $n=39\cdot2^4$, leads to the following problem
$$
\begin{aligned}
a&=780\,000,\\
x&=78,\\
y&=1249,\\
z&=780\,001,\\
x^2&=6084,\\
y^2&=1\,560\,001,\\
z^2&=608\,401\,560\,001.\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Undoubtedly you spotted the unwanted extra zero in the decimal expansion of $z^2$.

**A smaller example.** With $a=5^2$, $b=6\cdot2^2$ we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
a&=1200,\\
x&=12,\\
y&=49,\\
z&=1201,\\
x^2&=144,\\
y^2&=2401,\\
z^2&=1\,442\,401.\\
\end{aligned}
$$

**More examples.**
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
m&n&x&y&z&z^2\\
\hline
5^5&95\cdot2^5&19&524025&19007225&361274602200625\\
10\cdot5^6&2441\cdot2^6&4882&8124324&48820000676&2383392466004640456976\\
3\cdot5^7&1830\cdot2^7&1098&63263025&109800018225&12056044002210332150625
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Alas, I'm no longer sure that it would be trivial to show that we can proceed indefinitely.